# Postgresql daily inserts

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a log of an inventory that runs daily

Basically on my log table i want to sum how many units have status1, how many units have status2, etc for every day

is there a way to fill up my log table without having to do it manually every day?

My log table is
id serial,
date date,
count_of_status1 integer,
count_of_status2 integer

My insert query would be

```
insert into logtable(date, count_of_status1, count_of_status2)
select now(),  count(*) filter (where status =1), count(*) filter (where status = 2)
from mytable
```

How to make this insert to be done daily in an automated form rather than manually?

Comment: You can schedule a job to run the query at a set time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How to schedule stuff in sql?

Answer (score 0):

Use `crontab` to run that script via `psql`.

The simplest solution is often the most reliable one.
But make sure `crontab` reports errors instead of ignoring them.